# Подскажите jQuery плагин для сортировки блоков

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте, есть задача отсортировать блоки по data-атрибуту, например есть исходный код:

```html
<div data-sort="one">123</div>
<div data-sort="three">345</div>
<div data-sort="three">3534</div>
<div data-sort="two">56546</div>
<div data-sort="one">546546</div>
```

Надо после обработки плагином получить следующий результат:

```html
One
<div data-sort="one">123</div>
<div data-sort="one">546546</div>
Two
<div data-sort="two">56546</div>
Three
<div data-sort="three">345</div>
<div data-sort="three">3534</div>
```

Хочется именно плагин для этого подключить, желательно с callback api, что бы обработчики не сбрасывались

Answer (score 1):

```js
var obj = {
  one: 1,
  two: 2,
  three: 3
};
$("[data-sort]").get().sort(function(a, b) {
  return obj[a.dataset.sort] - obj[b.dataset.sort] || a.textContent - b.textContent
}).reduce(function(o, el) {
  var d = el.dataset.sort;
  if (!o[d]) {
    $("body").append(d);
    o[d] = true
  }
  $("body").append(el);
  return o
}, {});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-sort="one">123</div>
<div data-sort="three">345</div>
<div data-sort="three">3534</div>
<div data-sort="two">56546</div>
<div data-sort="one">546546</div>
```